# Version controlling laravel. Which files should i ignore?

Tags: git, version-control, laravel-5

When version controlling a laravel 5 app  with git, which files should I be ignoring?

Ultimately I understand that node_modules and vendor folders should be ignored, and composer.lock should not. I have got the general gist of that from seeing comments relating to laravel 4 VC, but I'm wondering before I make my first commit, if there's any other files I should be adding to my git ignore?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/gitignore-what-should-be-ignored)?

Comment: Thanks for the find, for some reason in all my searching either i missed it or it didn't come up. Either way, thankyou

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to GitHub](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Laravel.gitignore):

> ```
> vendor/
> node_modules/
>
> # Laravel 4 specific
> bootstrap/compiled.php
> app/storage/
>
> # Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
> bootstrap/cache/
> .env.*.php
> .env.php
> .env
>
> # Rocketeer PHP task runner and deployment package. https://github.com/rocketeers/rocketeer
> .rocketeer/
> ```

And [Joe](http://karan.goel.io/joe/) recommends this for Laravel and Composer:

> ```
> #### joe made this: http://goel.io/joe
>
> #####=== Laravel ===#####
>
> /bootstrap/compiled.php
> .env.*.php
> .env.php
> .env
>
> #####=== Composer ===#####
>
> composer.phar
> vendor/
>
> # Commit your application's lock file http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file
> # You may choose to ignore a library lock file http://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#lock-file
> # composer.lock
> ```